# Android Studio: Images do not show up while debugging app on phone, but do on the emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have inserted an image on a blank activity:

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/h2ua" />
```

The image works just fine while viewing in Design, and while testing the app using a Nexus 5 emulator on my Mac. But when i transfer it to my phone, it doesn't show up. I have the exact same setup in another activity where it works just fine on my phone. I have tried inserting text on top of the image in the blank activity, and that also shows up on my phone. Any ideas of what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah... I figured it out. The image was too big, max is 2048x2048, and mine was 2200.